# path selection with genetic algorithms

Tags: genetic-algorithm, path-finding

I have 17 nodes in my network with 3000 different paths in total. I have to select the best path using genetic algorithm. I'm confused about the approach! Should I have all paths as the population, or should I create a population same size as the nodes(17).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve], and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: This is the type of question that would be suitable for https://ai.stackexchange.com/. So, please, ask it there, and, to avoid cross-posting, delete it from here. I would also suggest that you describe more in detail what you mean by "best path". I guess you mean something like the shortest path/tour.